# Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a date - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, pivot

Estoy generando una tabla cruzada donde muestro a los operadores y cada día de semana con la cantidad de tickets que atendieron por día, en este caso estoy creando una función que reciba un parámetro de fecha y que calcule cada día de la semana para así generar mi tabla.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reporteSemana @FECHA DATE
AS
DECLARE @INICIO_SEMANA AS DATE
DECLARE @MARTES AS DATE
DECLARE @MIERCOLES AS DATE
DECLARE @JUEVES AS DATE
DECLARE @VIERNES AS DATE
DECLARE @SABADO AS DATE
DECLARE @FIN_SEMANA AS DATE

SET @INICIO_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 0) AS DATE)
SET @MARTES = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @MIERCOLES = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @JUEVES = DATEADD(DAY, 3, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @VIERNES = DATEADD(DAY, 4, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @SABADO = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @FIN_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 6) AS DATE)

SELECT CODIGO
    ,OPERARIO
    ,[@INICIO_SEMANA] AS LUNES
    ,[@MARTES] AS MARTES
    ,[@MIERCOLES] AS MIERCOLES
    ,[@JUEVES] AS JUEVES
    ,[@VIERNES] AS VIERNES
    ,[@SABADO] AS SABADO
    ,[@FIN_SEMANA] AS DOMINGO
FROM (
    SELECT a.OPER_CODIGO CODIGO
        ,a.OPER_NOMBRE + ' ' + a.OPER_APEPATER + ' ' + a.OPER_APEMATER OPERARIO
        ,CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) FECHAS
        ,COUNT(b.TCKT_NUMERO) CANTIDAD
    FROM OPERARIO a
    INNER JOIN BITACORA b ON a.OPER_CODIGO = b.OPER_CODIGO
    INNER JOIN TICKET c ON b.TCKT_NUMERO = c.TCKT_NUMERO
    WHERE CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) BETWEEN @INICIO_SEMANA
            AND @FIN_SEMANA
    GROUP BY a.OPER_CODIGO
        ,a.OPER_NOMBRE + ' ' + a.OPER_APEPATER + ' ' + a.OPER_APEMATER
        ,CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE)
    ) z
PIVOT(SUM(CANTIDAD) FOR FECHAS IN (
            [@INICIO_SEMANA]
            ,[@MARTES]
            ,[@MIERCOLES]
            ,[@JUEVES]
            ,[@VIERNES]
            ,[@SABADO]
            ,[@FIN_SEMANA]
            )) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.CODIGO ASC
GO
```

Al ejecutar mi procedimiento, SQL me arroja el siguiente error:

> Mens 8114, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento sp_reporteSemana, Línea
> 35 Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a date. Mens 473,
>
> Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento sp_reporteSemana, Línea 35 Se ha
> proporcionado el valor incorrecto "@INICIO_SEMANA" en el operador PIVOT.

Las tablas son las siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde:

1. TCKT_NUMERO es INT
2. TCKT_FINAL es DATETIME
3. OPER_CODIGO INT
4. El resto de columnas marcadas VARCHAR

Adjunto el script:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bSAuyQqhsic3lZUE1aNlVEcmc

Es un poco largo por eso lo subí a mi Drive.

Comment: Hola Wil. toma nota que el error que recibes no corresponde a tu consulta. El error menciona `@LUNES`, lo que no existe en tu SP. Asegúrate de proporcionar información exacta. De todos modos, parece que el problema tiene que que ver con el uso de variables en la cláusula `IN` del pivot. No creo que le guste eso. Si deseas mas ayuda, sería bueno que describas bien las tablas y los tipos de las columnas. Y mejor aun, si te montas un pequeño script con algunos datos de prueba para que podamos reproducir el error, eso sería ideal.

Comment: Acabo de adjuntar el Query, cierto lo de @ Lunes no es que no exista antes de adjuntar el script modifiqué eso por @ INICIO_SEMANA pero aún asi arroja dicho error.

Comment: @WilPedroso generé este script **http://rextester.com/OLCMCN15686** aquí podremos ver tus resultados y dar con el error, solo indicame si el error que me da al final también es el mismo que te está apareciendo a ti

Comment: Exactamente @Flxtr ese es el error que me arroja.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se comentó, no puedes usar variables con el `PIVOT`. Pero en vez de armar una consulta dinámica, puedes lograr el equivalente del pivot usando la función `SUM` con una condición por fecha. Haciéndolo de esa manera, puedes usar las variables sin problema:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reporteSemana @FECHA DATE
AS
DECLARE @INICIO_SEMANA AS DATE
DECLARE @MARTES AS DATE
DECLARE @MIERCOLES AS DATE
DECLARE @JUEVES AS DATE
DECLARE @VIERNES AS DATE
DECLARE @SABADO AS DATE
DECLARE @FIN_SEMANA AS DATE

SET @INICIO_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 0) AS DATE)
SET @MARTES = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @MIERCOLES = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @JUEVES = DATEADD(DAY, 3, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @VIERNES = DATEADD(DAY, 4, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @SABADO = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @FIN_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 6) AS DATE)

;with cte as (
  SELECT a.OPER_CODIGO CODIGO,
         a.OPER_NOMBRE + ' ' + a.OPER_APEPATER + ' ' + a.OPER_APEMATER OPERARIO,
         CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) FECHAS,
         COUNT(b.TCKT_NUMERO) CANTIDAD
    FROM OPERARIO a
    JOIN BITACORA b ON a.OPER_CODIGO = b.OPER_CODIGO
    JOIN TICKET c ON b.TCKT_NUMERO = c.TCKT_NUMERO
   WHERE CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) BETWEEN @INICIO_SEMANA AND @FIN_SEMANA
   GROUP BY a.OPER_CODIGO,
            a.OPER_NOMBRE + ' ' + a.OPER_APEPATER + ' ' + a.OPER_APEMATER,
            CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE)
)
select codigo,
       operario,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @inicio_semana then cantidad end),0) as lunes,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @martes then cantidad end),0) as martes,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @miercoles then cantidad end),0) as miercoles,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @jueves then cantidad end),0) as jueves,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @viernes then cantidad end),0) as viernes,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @sabado then cantidad end),0) as sabado,
       coalesce(sum(case when fechas = @fin_semana then cantidad end),0) as domingo
  from cte
 group by codigo, operario
 order by codigo, operario;
GO
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/UEK25296)</kbd> (¡Gracias a @Flxtr por pasar tu script a rextester!)

Comment: Una maravilla el RexTester :) creo que tu respuesta es más acertada que la mía dado que en el resultado se muestran fechas por día, por eso puse en mi respuesta *aunque no estoy seguro si es el resultado deseado*

Comment: @Flxtr: sí. hace tiempo que abandoné a SQLFiddle. Lo único con rextester es que, dependiendo de la base de datos, hay que hacer un drop de los objetos manualmente (ejemplo: MySQL, Oracle). SQLFiddle es mejor para eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ustedes por tomarse la molestía, les estoy muy agradecido, estaré leyendo el código y las funciones que usaste para poder aprender (no me gusta copiar solamente) :D

Answer (score 0):

Ese error te sale debido a que en un `PIVOT` no se pueden utilizar variables, por lo tanto, se recomienda construir una consulta dinámica y posteriormente ejecutarla con la sentenca `EXEC`, para que tu *Stored Procedure* no marque errores debe quedar de la siguiente forma (aunque no estoy seguro si es el resultado deseado):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_reporteSemana @FECHA DATE
AS
DECLARE @INICIO_SEMANA AS DATE
DECLARE @MARTES AS DATE
DECLARE @MIERCOLES AS DATE
DECLARE @JUEVES AS DATE
DECLARE @VIERNES AS DATE
DECLARE @SABADO AS DATE
DECLARE @FIN_SEMANA AS DATE

SET @INICIO_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 0) AS DATE)
SET @MARTES = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @MIERCOLES = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @JUEVES = DATEADD(DAY, 3, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @VIERNES = DATEADD(DAY, 4, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @SABADO = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @INICIO_SEMANA)
SET @FIN_SEMANA = CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @FECHA), 6) AS DATE)

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
    SELECT CODIGO
        ,OPERARIO
        ,''' + CAST(@INICIO_SEMANA AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS LUNES
        ,''' + CAST(@MARTES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS MARTES
        ,''' + CAST(@MIERCOLES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS MIERCOLES
        ,''' + CAST(@JUEVES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS JUEVES
        ,''' + CAST(@VIERNES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS VIERNES
        ,''' + CAST(@SABADO AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS SABADO
        ,''' + CAST(@FIN_SEMANA AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''' AS DOMINGO
    FROM (
        SELECT a.OPER_CODIGO CODIGO
            ,a.OPER_NOMBRE + '' '' + a.OPER_APEPATER + '' '' + a.OPER_APEMATER OPERARIO
            ,CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) FECHAS
            ,COUNT(b.TCKT_NUMERO) CANTIDAD
        FROM OPERARIO a
        INNER JOIN BITACORA b ON a.OPER_CODIGO = b.OPER_CODIGO
        INNER JOIN TICKET c ON b.TCKT_NUMERO = c.TCKT_NUMERO
        WHERE CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE) BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@INICIO_SEMANA AS VARCHAR(12))+ '''
                AND ''' + CAST(@FIN_SEMANA AS VARCHAR(12)) + '''
        GROUP BY a.OPER_CODIGO
            ,a.OPER_NOMBRE + '' '' + a.OPER_APEPATER + '' '' + a.OPER_APEMATER
            ,CAST(c.TCKT_FFINAL AS DATE)
        ) z
    PIVOT(SUM(CANTIDAD) FOR FECHAS IN (
                 [' + CAST(@INICIO_SEMANA AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                ,[' + CAST(@MARTES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                ,[' + CAST(@MIERCOLES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                ,[' + CAST(@JUEVES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                ,[' + CAST(@VIERNES AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                ,[' + CAST(@SABADO AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                ,[' + CAST(@FIN_SEMANA AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']
                )) AS pvt
    ORDER BY pvt.CODIGO ASC
'
EXEC(@SQL)
GO
```