# Condición en un COUNT de SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Necesito agregar una condición en un `COUNT` de un `SELECT` en `SQL SERVER`. Básicamente lo requerido es:

> La cantidad de registros agrupados por mes con algunas
>   exclusiones.

Éste es el `SELECT` que he realizado:

```
DECLARE @Anio INT = 2016;
DECLARE @Mes INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CodigoDireccion INT = 3;

SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

SELECT
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, rat1.fecha_ingreso), 3) AS NOMBRE_MES,
    COUNT(DISTINCT rat1.IDT1)
FROM
    ALLRATIONAL rat1
    INNER JOIN RAT_PA_ESTADOS est1 ON est1.EST_NOMBRE_ESTADO = rat1.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    INNER JOIN RAT_PA_ASOCIACION_ESTADOS aso1 ON aso1.ASO_CODIGO_ESTADO = est1.EST_CODIGO_ESTADO
WHERE
    YEAR(rat1.fecha_ingreso) = @Anio AND
    MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso) = COALESCE(@Mes, MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso)) AND
    aso1.ASO_CODIGO_DIRECCION = @CodigoDireccion AND
    (rat1.tipo_solicitud <> 'Analisis de Vulnerabilidades' AND rat1.tipo_solicitud <> 'Seguridad' AND rat1.tipo_solicitud <> 'Redes') AND
    (rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'Nessus TNS' AND rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'Requerimientos de Infraestructura' AND rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'Seguridad' AND rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'ODS ORACLE') AND
    rat1.proyectoid <> 0
GROUP BY
    MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso), LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, rat1.fecha_ingreso), 3)
ORDER BY
    MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso) ASC
```

***Nota***: Cabe recalcar que existen registros duplicados por la columna `IDT1`, por tal motivo uso un `DISTINCT` en el `COUNT`, para que me cuente una única vez los duplicados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado de la imagen anterior sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual está correcto y no tengo problemas, pero además de lo anterior debo agregar otra condición:

> Antes de contar el registro único, verificar por la columna `new_state` si en alguno de sus otros registros duplicados tiene asignado los estados `'Asignada_Area'` ó `'Asignada_Responsable'`, si es así, entonces se debe ir a verificar en otra tabla (`RAT_PA_AREAS_RESPONSABLE`) por medio de la columna `NOMBRET9` si el resultado de esa consulta es igual a lo que tenga la variable `@CodigoDireccion`, si es así, entonces **SÍ** debe contar ese registro único, de lo contrario **NO** se debe contar.

La otra tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, para intentar cumplir con ésta otra condición he modificado el `COUNT` del script con lo siguiente:

```
COUNT(
    DISTINCT (CASE WHEN (rat1.new_state = 'Asignada_Area' OR rat1.new_state = 'Asignada_Responsable') THEN
                        (CASE WHEN ((SELECT ARR_CODIGO_DIRECCION FROM RAT_PA_AREAS_RESPONSABLE WHERE ARR_NOMBRE_AREA = rat1.NOMBRET9) = @CodigoDireccion) THEN
                            rat1.IDT1
                        ELSE
                            NULL
                        END)
                    ELSE
                        rat1.IDT1
                END)
    ) AS TOTAL
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el script me muestra el siguiente error:

> No es posible usar una función de agregado con una expresión que
>   contiene un agregado o una subconsulta.

En resumen, ¿cómo puedo solucionar el error anterior? ó ¿de que otra forma puedo crear el script para obtener el resultado necesario?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Alonso, ¿a qué te refieres con *algunas exclusiones*?

Comment: Creo que no puedes usar `DISTINCT` dentro de `count`, tendrias que hacer una sub consulta...  `select count(c.campo), c.campo2 (TU CONSULTA) as c`

Comment: Otra forma seria ir agregando tus resultados en tablas temporales, después usar el `count`.

Comment: @Flxtr es una forma de decir lo que pongo en el WHERE, pero favor ignora esa frase: algunas exclusiones.. no es relevante en mi problema. Gracias.

Comment: En realidad sí se puede usar DISTINCT dentro de un COUNT @Cristina Carrasco Angulo.

Comment: Ah muy bien Alonso, ahora me queda claro :) Una pregunta, ¿sería posible contar con algún script donde se crean tablas y se insertan datos? Esto para poder replicar tu escenario justo como lo hicimos Sstan y yo en esta pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43400/error-al-convertir-el-tipo-de-datos-nvarchar-a-date-sql-server espero que sea posible, eso facilitaría y encontraríamos la respuesta más pronto

Comment: Tienes razón, debe ser el case entonces el que no se puede usar dentro del count... pero igual no estoy segura.  Creo que puedes hacer tu consulta de otra forma.  Yo lo separaría para ir sacando datos mas específicos... intentaré simular tu consulta.

Comment: @Cristina Carrasco Angulo el CASE también se puede utilizar dentro del COUNT, creo que mi problema es el CASE anidado con el SELECT, lo cuál no sé como se implementa correctamente allí. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Flxtr voy a intentar obtener esos scripts y los publico acá. Gracias.

Comment: Excelente, si logras obtener los scripts sería genial :)

Comment: en primera el distinct no es una buena practica, existen lugares "Bancos" en los cuales en sus buenas practicas lo indican, en segunda si metes un case when estas metiendo código duro, si después cambian tus datos tendrás que hacer cambios en tu consulta, como dice cristina si lo quieres sacar en una sola consulta puedes hacer subconsultas y si de plano se te hace muy complejo puedes usar tablas temporales o variables tipo tabla, también en algunos bancos no es permitido usar cursores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar mi problema, acá les dejo el script completo de como lo resolví:

```
DECLARE @Anio INT = 2016;
DECLARE @Mes INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CodigoDireccion INT = 3;

SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

SELECT
    tb.NOMBRE_MES,
    COUNT(DISTINCT
        (CASE WHEN (tb.new_state = 'Asignada_Area' OR tb.new_state = 'Asignada_Responsable') THEN
            (CASE WHEN tb.CodigoDireccion = @CodigoDireccion THEN
                tb.IDT1
            ELSE
                NULL
            END)
        ELSE
            tb.IDT1
        END)) AS TOTAL
FROM
    (SELECT
        MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso) AS NumeroMes,
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, rat1.fecha_ingreso), 3) AS NOMBRE_MES,
        (SELECT ARR_CODIGO_DIRECCION FROM RAT_PA_AREAS_RESPONSABLE WHERE ARR_NOMBRE_AREA = rat1.NOMBRET9 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS CodigoDireccion,
        rat1.IDT1,
        rat1.new_state
    FROM
        ALLRATIONAL rat1
        INNER JOIN RAT_PA_ESTADOS est1 ON est1.EST_NOMBRE_ESTADO = rat1.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        INNER JOIN RAT_PA_ASOCIACION_ESTADOS aso1 ON aso1.ASO_CODIGO_ESTADO = est1.EST_CODIGO_ESTADO
    WHERE
        YEAR(rat1.fecha_ingreso) = @Anio AND
        MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso) = COALESCE(@Mes, MONTH(rat1.fecha_ingreso)) AND
        aso1.ASO_CODIGO_DIRECCION = @CodigoDireccion AND
        (rat1.tipo_solicitud <> 'Analisis de Vulnerabilidades' AND rat1.tipo_solicitud <> 'Seguridad' AND rat1.tipo_solicitud <> 'Redes') AND
        (rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'Nessus TNS' AND rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'Requerimientos de Infraestructura' AND rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'Seguridad' AND rat1.NOMBRET4 <> 'ODS ORACLE') AND
        rat1.proyectoid <> 0) AS tb
GROUP BY
    tb.NumeroMes, tb.NOMBRE_MES
ORDER BY
    tb.NumeroMes
```

En resumen lo que hice fue anidar el `SELECT` principal dentro de otro `SELECT`, y en este otro `SELECT` realizar el cálculo del `COUNT`.

Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Excelente :-), lo que te sugerí en el primer comentario...  :-/ no le miraba otra forma, tal vez creando tablas temporales. U_U

Comment: Si correcto, gracias por la ayuda.